# PHP if statement inside HTML attribute

Tags: php, html, if-statement

I was wondering something. I'm looking at code from other trainees (who left, so I can't ask anything). I see the following:

```
<input type="text" 
name="name" 
class="form-control" 
placeholder="name" 
value="<?php if (isset($something)): echo 'bla'; 
             else: if(!empty($somethingelse)): echo 'bla2'; endif;"
>
```

This actually does look pretty ugly if I say so myself. I was wondering: is this actually a "good"/okay way to do it or is it really as bad as I think?

Comment: You're not closing both `if` conditions, there's an `endif;` lacking. And you need to exit PHP `?>` after as well, that would generate syntax errors.

Comment: In addition to the answers below also take a look at the "short tag" feature php offers: `<?=` instead `<?php echo...` Markup gets much more readable that way.

Comment: @Qirel Oops, forgot to add it, it is the concept though what matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always prefer to keep separated php and html parts. Here my suggestion:

```
<?php
    $value = isset($something)
        ? 'bla'
        : 'bla2'
    ;
?>
```

and

```
<input type="text" 
    name="name" 
    class="form-control" 
    placeholder="name" 
    value="<?php echo $value; ?>">
```

---

You can improve it more and more if you start to use twig. As you can see, there is no code here: its just a view.

```
<input type="text" 
    name="field_name" 
    class="form-control" 
    placeholder="field name" 
    value="{{ field_name }}">
```

At some point you can sent to that view variables and keep separated model (data and variables) form the view:

```
$value = isset($something)
    ? 'bla'
    : 'bla2'
;

$this->render('path/to/template.html.twig', [
    'field_name' => $value,
]);
```

Comment: Just as I thought; I'm spending like 2 days just on cleaning up the code and want to clean it as much as I can. What you do I thought of too, just was curious about how bad the code I showed actually is.

Comment: Every time you write code for yourself is clear for your self. At some point it is very important to write code for other people. It is the only way I know to force myself to write clean code.

Comment: Check my edit. In PHP world there are libraries and framework that can help you clean the code. I suggest you to learn all about MVC pattern.

Comment: And obviously I hope you like my suggestions, accepting mine as right response ^_^

Comment: Yeah, I know MVC. We used (thanks to the same guys who made this code) Codeigniter which i already kind of dislike. Nobody spent time on implementing Twig into it (one of the actual good developers on the project is now implementing it but is absent until Friday and didn't commit his stuff). But yeah, the suggestions you put are good ones. Love seeing you come up with Twig.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  <input type="text" 
    name="name" 
    class="form-control" 
    placeholder="name" 
    value="<?php echo isset($something) ? 'bla' : (!empty($somethingelse) ? 'bla2' : ''); ?>" >
```

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Also, I didn't ask for a replacement; I just wanted to know how bad the code is I showed. Even your example still bothers me, I like to use variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
<?php 
    if (isset($something)){
        $value = 'bla'; 
    }
    else if(!empty($somethingelse)){
       $value = 'bla2';
    }
?>

<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="name" 
value="<?php echo $value ?>" >
```

> First I'm setting the value in `$value` based on a condition and then I'm echoing that value in `value` attribute.